# How to index hbase data to solr

Tags: hadoop, indexing, solr, lucene, hbase

I have to index and search realtime data in solr. Data is stored in hbase columns. I have found a guide about this at [LINKEDIN](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hbase-solr-real-time-indexing-search-deepak)
But it is for Cloudera hadoop. It could not be used with apache hadoop.

Is there any alternate for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the hbase-indexer, https://github.com/lucidworks/hbase-indexer I believe is a fork of the one mention on your linkedin link.